# Data takes a few seconds to load when screen appears

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a product detail screen, and when loaded, the data takes a few seconds to appear. I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

[There is Main.storyboard screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMrnK.png)

Until load data I can see this view for few seconds:

[First view screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGEsK.png)

And when data loaded looks like:

[View when data loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QtmA.png)

There is code to push data on previous screen:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        productInt = indexPath.row
        let product = msproducts[productInt]
        nameToSend = product.name ?? ""
        descToSend = product.short_description ?? ""

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "infoViewAlu", sender: nil)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "infoViewAlu" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! ProduktInfoViewController

            ProgressHUD.show("Proszę czekać")
            controller.productName = nameToSend
            controller.productDesc = descToSend


        }

    }
```

And here is code to show this data in table:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var infoProductName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productDescription: UITextView!

    var productName: String = ""
    var productDesc: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        changeData(name: productName, desc: productDesc)
        title = productName 
    }

    func changeData(name: String, desc: String){
        infoProductName.text = name
        productDescription.text = desc
        ProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }
```

Can anyone tell me where is problem, why the screen is loading on two steps?

Comment: It shouldn't. You shouldn't have to use `ProgressHUD` with your current code. and it should be a "quick code execution". You are doing something else on mainthread.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be you are calling `progressHUD.show` before you segue. Try:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var infoProductName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productDescription: UITextView!

    var productName: String = ""
    var productDesc: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // remove this from **prepare for segue**
        ProgressHUD.show("Proszę czekać")
        //
        changeData(name: productName, desc: productDesc)
        title = productName 
    }

    func changeData(name: String, desc: String){
        infoProductName.text = name
        productDescription.text = desc
        ProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I did what you wrote, but it still doesn't work well

Answer (score 0):

Please remove all UI elements from detail screen and again redesign with new elements (don't copy past old element).

I have faced so many times this type of issue due to memory leak on iOS Framework for particular UI.

If you don't want to remove all elements from the detail screen then remove one by one element and check it. (You have to find particular UI element).